# iterate through dictionary until two conditions

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have a dictionary -  trains(of train, List(of station))
... 
station is class which has two properties as Boolean (station.src and station.dst)

I want to repeat loop on the dictionary until every station in the dictionary has this two properties equal true

```
    Do
        li = New List(Of train)(trains.Keys)
        For Each train In li
            Dim s = trains(train).Item(1)
            If s.name = sorc Then
                s.src = True
                s.dst = True
                GoTo n1
            End If
            lo = New List(Of train)(trains.Keys)
            For Each tr As train In lo
                If s.name_t = trains(tr).Item(2).name_t Then
                    s.src = True
                    trains(tr).Item(2).dst = True
                    GoTo n1
                End If
            Next
            trains.Remove(train)
n1:         Next train
        Loop Until (((each station.src in trains is true and each station.dst in trains is true))))
```

Comment: Can you please show your class definitions for `train` and `station`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit lost with what your code is doing. I had hoped to be able to simplify it down somewhat. It would be great if you could explain the logic behind it.

Nevertheless, the simple solution to your problem is this:

```
Loop Until trains.SelectMany(Function (kvp) kvp.Value).All(Function (s) s.src And s.dst)
```

---

I'd be interested to know how close this code is to giving you the result you want:

```
Dim sorcs = _
    From kvp In trains
    Where kvp.Value.Item(1).name = sorc
    Select New With { .s1 = kvp.Value.Item(1), .s2 = kvp.Value.Item(2) }

Dim pairs = _
    From kvp1 In trains
    Join kvp2 In trains On kvp1.Value.Item(1).name_t Equals kvp2.Value.Item(2).name_t
    Select New With { .s1 = kvp1.Value.Item(1), .s2 = kvp1.Value.Item(2) }

For Each pair In sorcs.Concat(pairs)
    pair.s1.src = True
    pair.s2.dst = True
Next
```

Comment: my dictionary is railway timetable .. every train has list of two stations the first as a source and the second as destination
I want to iterate through the dictionary until each station (except the station sorc that the user choose it as a source for his trip) acts as a source and destination too
because if it doesn't act as destination for any train that means it is not reachable

Comment: So you're trying to find out which stations are reachable from a starting station? Can you show the class definitions please?

Comment: no trying to find out which stations are not reachable to remove it 

Class station
    Public name As String
    Public t As Integer
    Public name_t As String = name & t
    Public src As Boolean = false
    Public dst As Boolean = false
    Public y As Integer
End Class

Comment: @AlKobtan - The opposite then. **Can you please show the class definitions?**

Comment: `Class station 
Public name As String 
Public t As Integer 
Public name_t As String = name & t 
Public src As Boolean = false 
Public dst As Boolean = false 
Public y As Integer 
End Class`

Comment: @AlKobtan - What about `train`?

Comment: `Class train 
public id as string 
public t as integer 
`

Comment: @AlKobtan - And one last thing - can you provide (by editing your question) the class initialization code? (i.e. sample data that I can load by copying, pasting, and running your code?

Comment: I think it would be difficult as my data being loaded from an access database !! how can I do that ??

Comment: @AlKobtan - You don't need your actual data, just a sample. You just have to create enough instances to be able to demonstrate your problem. Then we can see what the outcome should be before the code starts too.